# How to display two digits after decimal point in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I have table which has a column of `float` data type in `SQL Server`
I want to return my `float` datatype column value with 2 decimal places.

for ex: if i insert `12.3`,it should return `12.30`

if i insert `12`,it should return `12.00`

Answer (score 205, accepted):

```
select cast(your_float_column as decimal(10,2))
from your_table
```

`decimal(10,2)` means you can have a decimal number with a maximal total precision of 10 digits. 2 of them after the decimal point and 8 before.
The biggest possible number would be `99999999.99`

Comment: THANKS A LOT...IT SAVED ALL MY C# CODE CHANGING TIME.CAN YOU PLEASE EXPLAIN ABOUT WHAT 10 MEANS IN decimal(10,2)

Comment: `(10,2)` defines the precision of the decimal value. `10` digits and `2` digits after the comma.

Comment: @juergend hi, i'm trying a simple query like this `select cast(50/20 as decimal(5,2))
from sometable
limit 1` but the output it 2.00 (it should be 2.5).

Comment: @Moosa: Because it does the calculation before the casting. And then it already is rounded to `2`. Just use `select 50 / 20.0`. Since  `20.0` already is a decimal the conversion works as expected. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/8216

Comment: Does this 10 digit precision include only numbers like `12345678.91` or it also include comma like `1,234,5678.91` ?

Comment: @stom: Only the digits count.

Answer (score 29):

You can also do something much shorter:

`SELECT FORMAT(2.3332232,'N2')`

Comment: I pref this over the `cast(your_float_column as decimal(10,2))` cause i have no idea how big my decimal can be.

Comment: Note that this changes the type to NVARCHAR.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use below code which helps me:

```
select convert(numeric(10,2), column_name) as Total from TABLE_NAME
```

where `Total` is alias of the field you want.

Comment: I think it is a other way to do same thing.

Comment: That's a fair way to put it.

Answer (score 4):

You can also Make use of the Following if you want to Cast and Round as well. That may help you or someone else.

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(Column_Name, 2) AS DECIMAL(10,2), Name FROM Table_Name
```

Comment: select cast(round(12311313.1,2) as decimal(10,2)) from dual --> 12311313.1

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select cast(56.66823 as decimal(10,2))
```

This returns `56.67`.

Comment: Your answer is correct on what OP (Original Poster) requires but it is not descriptive. Also you are posting on a question that was asked 4 years back and has a correct answer similar and perhaps better than yours. It is good to answer on old post but only if it has an outdated answer.