# Convert string to number without losing precision and scale

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to convert a string to a number without loosing precision.

```
Example
select to_number('5.1') from dual
5.1
select to_number('5.10') from dual
5.1
```

How do i get 5.10 as the number in the second call ?

Comment: You aren't losing any precision or scale. Numbers don't have leading ot trailing zeros. 5.1 == 5.10 == 5.100000000. If you need to see trailing zeros then you need to convert back to a string, explicitly or via client default display settings.

Comment: you can get your answer from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20119300/12862527)

Comment: Thanks Alex for bringing me back to my senses :).Thanks Akash for the link.