# Take 2 digit after comma sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, i have column with data type float. i want to take 2 digit after comma

example
0.622
i want the result is
0.62
i already tried some solution from stack overflow but still the result is 0.61.

```
sum(CASE WHEN a.TOTALBUDGET>bo.Bobot*2 then bo.Bobot*2 else  a.totalbudget end) as UW_Rank
sum(CASE WHEN a.TOTALBUDGET>bo.Bobot*2 then bo.Bobot*2 else  CAST(ROUND(a.totalbudget,2,1)AS NUMERIC(18,2)) end) as UW_Rank_Test
```

[image: sample data]

thanks

Comment: please show the tried solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119282/how-to-display-two-digits-after-decimal-point-in-sql-server from here, and i have to sum first then take the 2 digit after comma

Comment: please edit your question and include the actual query that you have tried. Include any relevant samples data as well

Comment: How about some sample data ? Best is to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What you **see** is an artifact of the tool you use to display your resultset and the datatype of the column in question. Rounding can only be part of any solution - it is your tool that is responsible for the display. If you must do this in the query, you will need to also change the datatype as desired using CAST or CONVERT

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: problem solved, it must be round first and then sum. thanks all for the advice really appreaciate

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried round function.

```
declare @val float = '0.622'
SELECT ROUND(@val, 2);
```